# How do we test notebooks that use delta live table

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I cannot execute the delta live table code in the notebook. I always have to create a DLT pipeline by going into workflows tab. Is there a easy way to test the delta live table code in notebook

Thanks

Comment: I just published a blog post about unit & integration testing in DLT pipelines: https://alexott.blogspot.com/2022/12/delta-live-tables-recipes-implementing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging Delta Live Table pipelines is challenging. Luckily Souvik Pratiher has created an [open-source library](https://github.com/souvik-databricks/dlt-with-debug) for debugging Delta Live Table notebooks on regular Databricks clusters.

Comment: i tried it, it works well. Need to test more.